# Cannot get python code to run specutils continuum fitting command properly

Tags: astropy

I am learning specutils and have run into problems with the continuum fitting portion of the program. The program returns an "UnitsConversionError."

I am using Python 3.7 with Spyder 3.3.3. The program returns the error given above when I use the run command. If I use the same lines of code in the Spyder console the code returns an empty graph.

```
from specutils import Spectrum1D
lamb = 10**specdata['loglam']*u.AA
flux = specdata['flux']*10**-17*u.Unit('erg cm-2 s-1 AA-1')
spec = Spectrum 1D(spectral_axis=lamb, flux=flux)

lines = plt.step(spec.spectral_axis, spec.flux)

from specutils.fitting import fit_generic_continuum
cont_norm_spec = spec/fit_generic_continuum(spec)(spec.spectral_axis)
lines = plt.step(cont_norm_spec.wavelength, cont_norm_spec.flux)
plt.xlim(654*u.nm, 660*u.nm)
```

The result should be two graphs. The first is the entire spectrum. (File loaded was not included.) The second should be a subsection of that graph. The second graph does not show up. Instead a "UnitsConversionError" is returned. If I run the "lines =..." and below in the console an empty window is returned.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
lamb = 10**specdata['loglam']*u.AA
```

you are converting the wavelength to Angstroms.

But here:

```
plt.xlim(654*u.nm, 660*u.nm)
```

you are asking it to plot in nanometres. Try giving it:

```
plt.xlim(6540*u.AA, 6600*u.AA)
```

Unless there is something else, this change should fix it. In other words it needs consistent units.